# How do I link the CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER in a qt creator project builded with cmake?

Tags: qt, c++17, qt5, qt-creator, cgal

I need to make an application that draws a Voronoi diagram given a set of points, for this I plan to use CGAL.

It asks me to add the "CGAL-Qt5" installation prefix to the folder in which one of these files is located "CGAL-Qt5Config.cmake cgal-qt5-config.cmake" inside the "CMakeLists.txt" file, the problem is that I can't find the folder where "CGAL-Qt5Config.cmake cgal-qt5-config.cmake" are in my system (I'm using ubuntu).

I clarify that I did install CGAL-Qt5 with the "libcgal-qt5-dev" package
[installed package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPYNB.png)

I have tried to use the directory "/usr/include/CGAL/" but it doesn't work. I have also used "find -name CGAL-Qt5Config.cmake" and "find -name cgal-qt5-config.cmake" it finded nothing.

Comment: Did you tried the example draw_voronoi_diagram_2.cpp ? It comes with a CMakeLists.txt that can directly be opened in QTCreator.